# WebScrapping - Python - Selenium + BeautifullSoup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, linkedin-api

I`m trying to build a web scrapper to get user profile information such as `name, location, experience, skills and languages`

The problem I'm facing is:

[image: Example profile]

[image]

inside each `li` tag contains the text I'm looking for

[image]

When I look to get information on `Experience` the section id changes for each profile, and if I try to use a different **tag, for example a div** brings me information from other fields that I do not  need.
Other thing, as you can see on the picture it shows 'div' id = 'experience', but as this tag do not nest any parent tag I cannot use it to extract the data.

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: I did as you asked

Comment: Instead of **image** based HTML _**text**_ based HTML  would have been better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing: `soup.findAll('div')`
for finding all div's and then just split the output, so you can get the id that you want ;D

Comment: Could be a solution, the main issue on that is that for each profile page we would have a few differences.

Comment: Then just findAll UserID's